# The distinction between "over there" and "over yonder."

Tags: meaning, differences, dialects

For most native English speakers the word 'yonder' is either archaic or poetic. For many native speakers in the Southern United States however, it is still a word in common but declining use. Those who still use the term rhyme it with 'wonder' rather than 'wander.'

Having used the term all my life I notice that there is a distinction between the meaning of the phrases 'over there' and 'over yonder' which I have never seen mentioned in a dictionary.

One may say "The ball is over there where you are" but not "The ball is over yonder where you are." However, one can say either "The ball is over there in the bushes" or "The ball is over yonder in the bushes."

The distinction appears to be that 'yonder' is somewhere distant from both the speaker and the 'spoken to' whereas 'there' just means somewhere distant from the speaker.

Can anyone who also uses the term 'yonder' in everyday speech or someone familiar with English dialects verify this distinction.

Comment: My (perhaps mistaken, beware!) understanding was there used to be 3 categories of proximity, right *here*, where I am, over *there*, a distance away, and waaaay over *yonder*, a great distance away. This is still evidence in some other romance languages, like Spanish, with its *aqui* /  *alli* / *alla* trio (this last being frequently translated as *yonder*). I don't know about its use in modern day English dialects. I've never encountered the "distant from both you and me" concept.

Comment: I've lived in the US for all of my 68 years, and I've never been aware of a distinction that wasn't just in terms of absolute difference -- "yonder" more distant than "there" -- though tone of voice and arm motions are also a big part of it.  However, I've never spent much time in the rural South.

Comment: I don't see how "yonder" rhymes with "wonder" unless you pronounce both "wonder" and  "wander" the way they are spelled. Over here (UK) we pronounce "wonder" as "wunder", and "wander" as "wonder", although recently on BCC TV I am hearing pronunciations alien to me.

Comment: If I used the word **yonder** at all, I would only say "yonder farm is two leagues distant" meaning, it is not nearby. In UK it is archaic.

Comment: @WeatherVane In the US South, 'yonder' rhymes with 'thunder' and 'plunder.'

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales interesting, even in UK some pronunciation varies locally. For example "luck" and "duck" in the north are said as "look" and "dook".

Comment: That is because yonder isn't properly an "at" locative form at all, it is used as a "to" locative. The 'at' form was *yond*, and that really is archaic, even in the Inland South. "is over there" vs "went over yonder"

Comment: 'Yon' is still used - or was when I was there - in Glasgow. 'Yon ijit uwer there.' (Translation : That fine looking fellow somewhat distant from us.)

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales That's not the way Jed Clampett said it.

Comment: In the song "Orange Blossom Special," Johnny Cash sang "Lookie, yonder coming, coming down that railroad track..."  And he pronounced it to rhyme with fonder. And he came from rural Arkansas.

Comment: @StevenLittman No. those aren't the lyrics. There is no "yonder come". Yonder isn't used to locate "from" where. The [Lyrics](https://www.google.com/search?q=orange+blossom+special+lyrics&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=Orange+blossom+special&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.13436j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) are Look a-yonder comin'
Comin' down that railroad track
Hey, look a-yonder comin'
Comin' down that railroad track
It's the Orange Blossom Special
Bringin' my baby back

Comment: @Phil Sweet  You're right, it's embedded in my mind from the way I first (thought I) heard it about 50 years ago, but that's still not the point.  He doesn't sing "yunder," and that's the point. (And it still sounds like "Lookie yonder" to me, but Google says otherwise.)

Comment: @StevenLittman Perhaps Johnny Cash was prevailed upon to pronounce 'yonder' to rhyme with 'ponder' despite his upbringing. I think I was a teenager before I heard that pronunciation in Romeo & Juliet. But then again, I was in college before I heard anyone say 'climbed' when I had only ever heard 'clumb.' As far as country music lyrics go, how many singers say 'cotton balls' instead of the correct 'cotton bolls' in the song "Cotton Fields"?

Comment: @DanBron The Spanish three-way distinction is actually different from the one you said. These work like 1st, 2nd, 3rd person so *aqui* is close to the speaker, *ahí* is close to the person addressed (as in the common expression *por ahí*), and *allí* is close to neither me nor thee. The *-a* versions you can think of as being more area-related than point-related. (*Ven aquí* = Come here) ≠ (*Ven acá* = Come over here). So *acá* is more a hereabouts and *allá* is more a thereabouts that's around neither of us. (There is no second-person version of that because *ahá* would sound just like *a*.)

Comment: @tchrist That sounds similar to the way I learned to use 'yonder' growing up in Texas in the 1940s and 1950s. Although no one would misunderstand if someone said "Over yonder where you are" one would more likely hear "Over there where you are" and reserve 'yonder' for a distance away from both speaker and listener. I suppose it is rather academic since even in the South the word is becoming archaic. Perhaps a lost distinction between 'there' and 'yonder' contributed to the demise of the latter term.

Comment: @DanBron From your first comment about 3 proximaties in Spanish...you missed _aca_...that's 4

Comment: You certainly wouldn't say "Is Ben over yonder with you?"

Comment: It could simply be the case that, since 'yonder' implies a much further distance than 'there,' that 'yonder' is out of earshot of whomever you are speaking to. So 'yonder' is by its nature far away from both the speaker and the 'spoken to.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be a mistake to assume that *yonder* generally represents a greater distance from the speaker than *there* does. Either term, unadorned, is ambiguous as to distance. The key to conveying a sense of how distant a thing "there" or "yonder" actually is lies in the modifier or modifiers attached to it, although some resulting phrases (such as "over there" and "over yonder") remain exceedingly vague as to distance. Consider, for example, the popular World War I song "[Over There](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over_There)" by George M. Cohan, where *there* referred to "in Europe"—that is, across the Atlantic Ocean.

Because many people today do not use *yonder* as a standard part of their vocabulary, they may associate it with a particular usage that implies considerable distance, as in the song "[Way Down Yonder in New Orleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Way_Down_Yonder_in_New_Orleans)." But for people who use *yonder* regularly, I suspect, the range of distances that the term can comfortably comprehend is quite broad. My grandfather, who was born in western Kentucky in 1903, used *yonder* occasionally and variably, often to indicate an indefinite place—for example, "the cows are grazing out yonder," meaning that the cows are grazing in a nearby pasture but it isn't entirely clear which pasture or which part of a single pasture they are in.

You can get a sense of the range of use of *yonder* in everyday speech in regions where the word was common by looking at recorded examples of its use (in the sense of "there; at or in that place") in Harold Wentworth, *American Dialect Dictionary* (1944):

> 'Yonder it is, Squire' [1871, Georgia]
>
> 'It [the river] rises yander' [1881 Tennessee]
>
> 'a-standin' out yander' [1888, Georgia]
>
> 'The road is back yander' [1895, Kentucky, Tennessee, North Carolina]
>
> 'You must do this or go down yander, one!' [1902, Illinois]
>
> Denotes a long distance & an uncertain direction. 'His folks live back yander,' meaning no particular direction or distance. 'I heerd he was going back yander where he came from.' [1903, Missouri]
>
> Extremely common in 'over yonder' [1905, Arkansas]
>
> '[a]way yonder' = far [1906–9, Arkansas]
>
> A noun used with a preposition to express a specified place. 'In yonder,' = in the place specified. 'Over yonder' refers often to the future life. 'Look ayonder.' [1908, Alabama, Georgia]
>
> 'It's yunder over in the corner' [1909 Massachusetts]
>
> 'That's my gat down yonder.' [1911, Massachusetts]
>
> 'It is in yonder' [1915, West Virginia]
>
> 'See that tree over yender?' [1917, Ohio]
>
> 'Out yonder' and 'The woods back yonder' [1917, Vermont, New York; 1920, North Carolina]
>
> 'He went yander right now!' = disappeared in haste [1923, Missouri]
>
> 'He is down yander' [1925, West Virginia]
>
> 'I got another pipe yonder home ... away down yonder in dem thickest pine woods ... a-sleepin right yonder on de bed ... Youcould stay yonder to school ... de boat yonder on de river ... I ain' got a stick of wood yonder home' [1928 South Carolina]
>
> 'Looky yonder' = Look there. Used of any small or great distance. [1930s, West Virginia]
>
> 'Over yonder on the grinsad.' [1930, Maine]
>
> 'that hollow back yander' [1936, Kentucky]
>
> 'round yonder back of that piney pint' [1937, Kentucky]
>
> 'There he goes! Yander, see 'im!' [1938, Kentucky]
>
> 'Gone too fur yonder' [1938, Florida]
>
> 'Look yonder ... sitting right up yonder ahead of me ... Look a-yonder [1940, Gulf of Mexico states]
>
> 'over yonder ... is where it ends ... from here to yonder' [1940, Mississippi]
>
> 'Yonder comes Ced ... Look comin' up the street yonder' [1940, Arkansas]
>
> 'that beech grove down yander' [1941, Kentucky]
>
> 'Yonder atop the roof' [1941, West Virginia]

Wentworth selected these examples mainly to show variants in pronunciation, prepositional use, and regional distribution of *yonder*; but the examples also convey a sense of how broadly applicable *yonder* was to different situations for speakers who used the term frequently. For some of them, at least, *yonder* seems coextensive with *there* as a term for position or distance. Such speakers might at times use *yonder* in connection with distant locations, but they might also use it in reference to the corner of a room they were sitting in, for example, or a bed elsewhere in the same house.

The decisive factor in defining how distant *yonder* is for a particular speaker, in other words, is whether the speaker uses the word frequently and widely in situations where other speakers might use *there*, or whether the speaker uses it relatively rarely and in particular contexts—for example, as part of a longer set phrase such as "way over yonder."

Comment: That is an interesting collection and all seem appropriate to my understanding of 'yonder' meaning somewhere away from both speaker and listener. But if my understanding of the term ever had a wide usage, it would probably have been noticed and remarked upon, so I conclude that I learned a perhaps local, idiosyncratic distinction.

Comment: "But for people who use yonder regularly, I suspect, the range of distances that the term can comfortably comprehend is quite broad. "  That is because *yonder* has nothing whatsoever to do with distance. It is about direction only. Distance along that direction has to be communicated separately.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I've always vieweed "there" as being a more specific, perhaps closer, location, while "yonder" is a more vague, perhaps further, location.  "The ball is over there"would seem to indicate a more specific, perhaps closer, location than "The ball is over yonder" does.

Answer (score 0):

I think that might make sense. In some languages there are different location words which are associated with personal pronouns. So for example, in Portuguese:

aqui - here where I am

aí - there where you are

lá - there away from both me and you

But there are also degrees of distance:

ali - there away from both me and you, but not very far

Answer (score 0):

My wife is not a native English speaker. She heard the phrase while playing the Witcher 3 and she did not understand what it meant, but to me it was obvious. She asked what it meant to me, and I said, "not here or near, but away at a distance toward the horizon, direction usually indicated with an arm motion". After reading the responses here, as educational as they are, I think my off-the-cuff response properly encapsulates the phrase.

Comment: I tend to agree, but - although I love TW3 - most of your answer is not really relevant to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Pointing out "over there" is when I can see the location I am pointing out. Pointing out "over yonder" is when I don't have a line of sight to the location I'm pointing, maybe because of a treeline or even a shed. Not distance but rather line of sight related in my usage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).